# Publish a Google Drive SDK app to Trusted Testers

Tags: google-drive-api

I have followed the steps described in https://developers.google.com/drive/listing and have created a private Chrome Web Store listing for my app.
The owner of the Chrome Web Store listing (i.e., myself) can see the application and was able to install it in his Google Drive. 
However the others trusted testers cannot see the app (it does not appear in search results in the Chrome Web Store, and it does not appear in the "Connect more apps" in their Google Drive).
How can I make the private listing visible to them ?

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the issue: I was trying another "trusted tester" account in the same Chrome browser as my main account. For some reason, it doesn't work (I can't install the Chrome Web Store application "twice" in the same Chrome).
So I created a new Chrome user for my other tester account, so as to have a clean Chrome environment, and I was able to install the app from the Chrome Web Store again in this new environment.